# Is it legal to read into an array that doesn't have space for the null terminator?

Tags: c++

Every C string is terminated with the null character when it is stored in a C-string variable, and this always consumes one array position.

So why is this legal:

```
char name[3];
std::cin >> name;
```

when a 3 letter word "cow" is input to `std::cin`?

Why is it allowing this?

Comment: It's not legal, it's undefined behavior. It's "just" not checked by the compiler. C and C++ generally allow progammer to do lots of possibly invalid stuff without any checks. Here, for example, `>>` assumes that the right operand is `char*` (pointer-to-a-char), and you cannot get size of the array which it points two. It is possible to write a separate `>>` for arrays which checks size, but noone bothered to, AFAIK.

Comment: C++ is not babysitting you. It will allow you to write outside the size of a buffer, you as a programmer has a responsibility. To write safer code use the STL string to input your string data. E.g. std::string input; std::in >> input; this will do the memory managment for you.

Comment: What makes you think it's legal?

Comment: You are responsible your self to make sure your buffer is big enough, Worst thing is that is is undefined behaviour. So Although It might work atm, you ship your broken code and you'll end up frustrating your clients. You turn back to your C++ book and think, I should have used a std::string.

Comment: @yeputons: `>>` nowadays detects the `char[3]` because it's overloaded.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler cannot know what input you will be giving at runtime, so it cannot say that you will be doing something illegal. If the input fits in the array, then it's legal.

Prior C++20:

The behaviour of the program is undefined. Never do this.

Since C++20:

The input will be truncated to fit into the array, so the array will contain the string "co".

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed because the memory management is left to the programmer.
In this case the error occurs at run-time and it's impossible for the compiler to spot it at compile time.

What you are getting here is an undefined behavior, where the program can crash, can go on smoothly, or present some odd behavior in the future.

Most likely here you are overflowing the allocated memory by one byte which will be stored in the first byte of the subsequent declared variable, or in other addresses which may or may not be already filled with relevant information.

You eventually may experience an abort of the execution if - for example - some read-only memory area is overwritten, or if you point your Instruction Pointer to some invalid area (again, by overwriting its value in memory)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "legal".   In context of your question, there is no precise meaning.

According to the standard (at least before C++20) your code (if supplied with that input) has undefined behaviour.  When behaviour is undefined, any observable outcome is permitted, and no diagnostics are required.

In particular, there is no requirement that an implementation (the compiler, the host system, or anything else) diagnose a problem (e.g. issue an error message), take preventative action (e.g. electrocute the programmer for entering "cow" before hitting the enter key), or take recovery action (e.g. truncate the input to `"co"`).

The reason the standard allows such things is a combination of;

- allowing implementation freedoms.  For example, the standard permits but does not require your host  system to electrocute the user for entering bad input to your program - but doesn't prevent an evil-minded system developer providing hardware and driver support to do exactly that;
- technical infeasibility or technical difficulty.  In a simple case like your code might be easy to detect.  But, in more complicated programs (e.g. your code is buried away among other code) it might be impossible to identify a problem.  Or, it might be possible, but take much longer than a programmer is willing/able to spend waiting.

In short, the C++ standard does not coddle the programmer.   The programmer - not the standard, not the compiler - is responsible for avoiding undefined behaviour, and responsible if a program with undefined behaviour does undesirable things.